# Android doesn't dump error trace on runtime crash

Tags: android, eclipse, runtime-error, android-logcat

The only way I can see the runtime error trace in LogCat is when I edit/save changes to code and an Eclipse popup asks me if I want to Disconnect the device.

How do you make it show the trace by default right when it crashes? (As it is, all I see is the blank lack-of-source-code page where it tries to show me the Android source that isn't there)

Edit: This example is on an actual device. When using the emulator I simply can't find a way to see the error trace

Workaround: For now my work around is on a crash I do a quick key+backspace+ctrl-s and that prompts the "Hot Code Swap Failed" dialog, then I click "Disconnect" and the runtime error finally shows up in LogCat. Also, I'm much more careful about dumping the exception trace to LogCat in my Try/Catches

Comment: In eclipse do you have the LogCar open in the bottom tab where you can watch the messages?

Comment: Yea, but for some reason the exceptions only show up in LogCat in that weird circumstance

Comment: Add Flurry or Bugsense in your code and it will email you the stacktrace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get the LogCat, or any various windows to open in Eclipse hit the icon in the bottom left corner and select whichever you need.  Then you can watch the inner workings in real time on the screen in a permanent separate window.